# How to root the HTC One S (VilleC2)

Tags: cyanogenmod, rooting, custom-roms, htc-one-s

I finally managed to unlock the bootloader of my HTC One S.

Now I want to root it to install CyanogenMod but I can only find guides for the normal HTC One S. However, it is a One S **VilleC2**. As far as I know, flashing the wrong ROM could brick my phone.

Well, I was able to find exactly one guide but I would have needed the HTC Sync Manager which I cannot install because the installation gives me a Blue Screen of Death on windows 8.1... So I'd need a guide that works without the Sync Manager (Windows 8.1 or Linux - Linux preferred).

Unfortunately I'm completely new to rooting Android and don't know what to pay attention to while doing so.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I root my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device)

Comment: Check the duplicate link on the flagging, then check out this Google search - [https://www.google.com/search?redir_esc=&redir_esc=&hl=en&client=ms-android-virgin-us&source=android-browser-suggest&v=210020111&qsubts=1419535865037&devloc=0&q=one%20s%20villec2](https://www.google.com/search?redir_esc=&redir_esc=&hl=en&client=ms-android-virgin-us&source=android-browser-suggest&v=210020111&qsubts=1419535865037&devloc=0&q=one%20s%20villec2) or just type __One S VilleC2__

Comment: @HasH_BrowN Not again. Please read the [rooting tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info). We don't close as duplicate to that since January 2012 :)